# SImple question for CSS about scroll - I was clone-coding Facebook

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, frontend

When I use Facebook's dashboard, and I just scroll down the browser, I can see only the main part(newsfeed at home) scrolled to down with infinite scrolling and another parts are fixed on side and top of the screen. How do I implement like this? I mean, scrollbar is on the right side of browser on the Facebook while the scrolling part is just the main contents part, not the inner side(I mean, not at the right side of the inner part - newsfeed). I tried to copy and clone-coding the Facebook and the left side of main(name, Friends, Watch, Group, Events, etcs) scrolled down together.

Real Question is -
How can I just scroll down the part I want, not the whole part?

Please check the image below to make sure what this question is clearly about.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/00uB6.png

Comment: it's simple... but we have to see your code and what you tried so far to help solve YOUR issue

Comment: It would be huge code, I mean, more than 200+ lines of code because I did super hard code Lol, so I just asked for the simple principle or formula about that issue ;( sorry for being lazy but Is there any a simple formula or principle about this? ;)

Comment: @Lee learn about `position: sticky` in CSS

Comment: try to use `poistion:fixed` to your header and `position:sticky` to your menu

Comment: @RameshReddy Omg, How can I tag his name just above Lol xD I'm new to this.. ;) Thank you so much, I'll just give it a try.

Comment: you can see my answer down below using html and css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an **example** of structure

```css
.header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  background: blue;
  width: 100%;
}

.wrap {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  top: 15px;
}

.menu {
  width: 100px;
  position: fixed;
}

.main {
  height: 1500px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-left:100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="header">Header</div>
  <div class="menu">side menu</div>
  <div class="main">main</div>
</div>
```

Comment: no problem :) joeun haru bonaesipsio! (LOL i have no korean keyboard)

Answer (score 0):

Check this sample design below. This might help.
Basically, I have used the flex layout as the one to create the page and then I've hidden the scrollbar for the news feed container.

```js
for (var i = 1; i <= 200; i++) {
  document.getElementsByClassName("container2")[0].innerHTML += 'scrollable area ' + i + '<br />';
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

.main-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container1 {
  background-color: #a00;
  flex: 0.2;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  align-self: flex-start;
}

.container2 {
  background-color: #0a0;
  flex: 0.8;
  overflow: auto;
}

.container2::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <!-- keeps both containers -->
  <div class="container1">
    <!-- container1 has page links, group links (left side of facebook) -->
    Unscrollable area. This will contain the page links, group links and others. This is the left side on facebook.
  </div>
  <div class="container2">
    <!-- container2 has the scrollable news feed -->
    This is the news feed. You can use javascript to load more content when user reaches the scroll end of this element. <br />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! It really helps me a lot!